# Developing for iOS with Phonegap - substitute index.html

Tags: cordova, xcode5

Morning,

I have created my first iOS app using Phonegap-2.9.0 & Xcode5 (previously I have only done it for Android using Eclipse)

In Android/Eclipse there is a main_activity class which has a function looking something like:
`super.loadUrl("file/android_assets/www/index.html");`

In the Android version of the app I am building, I replaced the URL with an external web based URL. This worked fine and was cleaner than using InAppBrowser (no InAppBrowser menu bar etc)

How can I do this with Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open classes/AppDelegate.m

Find the following line

`//self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";`

replace index.html with the required URL.

Uncomment it.

Answer (score 0):

In cordova 2.9.0 we have a config file. In this file you will see content tag here, you can mention your launch file name over there.

```
<content src="index.html" />
```